# How can I change msgbox font in Matlab (GUI)?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am making a GUI in Matlab and wondering if there is any way to change the font size of message box? I am using the following command:

h = msgbox('Operation Completed');

I am not using GUIDE.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (R2015a):

```
h = msgbox('Operation Completed');
ah = get( h, 'CurrentAxes' );
ch = get( ah, 'Children' );
set(ch, 'FontName', 'Nimbus Roman No9 L');
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however does not work for me. My matlab is R2014b.

Comment: It says: There is no FontName property on the Image class.

Comment: This actually is not due to it not necessarily working on R2014b. It sounds as though this is actually due to their being an image in the dialogue box. See below.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the code to work with images:

```
h = msgbox('fgsdf','sdfsd','error');
object_handles = findall(h);
set( object_handles(6), 'FontSize', 20)
```

You may need to check the index.